# SharePoint 2013 Log Error - dbo.proc_MIP_GetScheduledJobsInInterval

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, logging

I've recently check the log files of my SharePoint 2013 installation and I found that I've an exception error that occur quite often.

The log says that SharePoint could not find stored procedure 'dbo.proc_MIP_GetScheduledJobsInInterval'.

I know that this stored proc is used for the user profile import but I've got no error while I use SharePoint and manage profile user.

Answer (score 0):

Have you applied a patch to your farm lately? Can you think of anything that may have changed recently to cause this (e.g. modifications to your user profile service application)?

I had a case once where I applied a CU and a couple of stored procedures in user profile databases went missing. I ended up creating a new user profile service and copying the missing artifacts from the new DBs to the old ones.

Or, if you don't have the stomach for that, you could just rebuild your user profile service app.

Comment: I've applied the CU of April 2013 and October 2013 few days ago.  No, for me, nothing have changed recently for the user profile service app.  I will check to rebuild my user profile service app.

Comment: Applying CUs will affect all of your databases. That must have been it. Good luck with the rebuild and I'm glad that I could answer your question!